# Why did Hanuman fight with Lord Rama?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman

I heard there was one occasion where a god and his devotee fought a great battle against each other. It's the case of Lord Rama vs. Hanuman.

Being a true devotee, why did Hanuman fight against his [cherished god](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%ADa-devat%C4%81_(Hinduism)), Lord Rama?

Comment: This story was told and re-told my Guru, Shri Shivabalayogi Maharaj. It's validity is contained in the truth of its message, that the name of God and the faith we have in that name is more powerful than the rules and regulations of religion. Shri Shivabalayogi also said, "There is no God in religion, only politics."

Comment: As a young girl i have watched a movie named ShriRam Hanuman.Yudhdham(war).In which atlast Sriram used to send a series of arrows towards Hanuman , butto no accord.for Hanuman will be b chanting "Om SriRam " with full dedication n bakthi. But I do not remember the reason for the war.

Comment: Another version [Another version of the incident](http://www.bhagavatam-katha.com/holy-name-story-who-is-greater-lord-almighty-or-his-divine-name/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As far as I know, this story has no scriptural basis; it may just be folklore.  The story as I remember it goes roughly as follows: the king of Kashi was once in Ayodhya, perhaps during the coronation of Rama, and he insulted the short-tempered sage Vishwamitra who was there at the time.  Vishwamitra was furious and he told Rama that he wanted the king's head at his feet by sunset.  Rama was duty-bound to obey, as Vishwamitra was his guru, so he promised that he would do that.  The king of Kashi, terrified for his life since Rama was immeasurably powerful, sought refuge in Hanuman.  Hanuman agreed to protect the king, and so Rama and Hanuman were forced to battle each other.  Rama tried launching arrows at Hanuman, but the arrows fell to the ground when Hanuman kept chanting Rama's name, because Rama's name is even more powerful than his arrows.  So they were at a stalemate, and then they found a way to resolve the situation: they made the king of Kashi bow down to Vishwamitra, so that technically his head would be at his feet.

I don't think this story is told in any Hindu scriptures; I originally learnt it myself from some comic book for kids.  But I just found the story in the book "Hanuman's Tale: The Messages of a Divine Monkey" by Phillip Lutgendorf (pages 162-164):

> [T]he king of Kashi happens to be journeying to Ayodhya to pay his respects to Rama.  En route, he meets the sage Narada, who requests a favor of him.  When the king agrees, Narada tells him to show respect to everyone in Rama's court, but to ignore sage Vishwamitra....  The ever-volatile Vishwamitra is enraged by the slight and informs Rama of it, calling it a stain on the honor of his court.  Rama's brow darkens; he removes three arrows from his quiver and vows that he will take the life of the king of Kashi before the sun sets....  The king is trembling like a leaf, however, so Narada offers a suggest for how he might yet save himself: "Go to [Hanuman's mother] Lady Anjana and ask for her protection." ... When he then reveals that his would-be executioner is Rama hismelf, Anjana is troubled.  "This will be difficult", she says, then adds, "still, I'll try."  At this moment Hanuman arrives and bows at his mother's feet.... [S]he makes him, in turn, promise three times to assist her....  His mother reminds him of the great dharma of sheltering the week and of the fact that she has given her word.  Hanuman says he will try to find a way out
>
> Hanuman flies back to Ayodhya with the king and brings him to the bank of the Sarayu.  He tells him to wade waist-deep into the water and remain there, repeating Rama's name.  Meanwhile, Hanuman presents himself at court, bows to Rama, ... [and] asks that henceforth he be permitted to guard those who repeat Rama's name, and further, that as long as he does so, no power in the universe, - "not even God himself" - should be able to cause them harm.  Rama readily agrees, whereupon Hanuman ... rushes back to the riverbank[.]...  Rama is soon informed of this and becomes furious.  He takes one of his arrows, charges it with mantras for the destruction of the king of Kashi, and fires it right from the palace.  But the arrow halts in mid-air just in front of the king[.]...
>
> Meanwhile, Vishwamitra too arrives on the scene, brooding over the curious crisis he preciptated.  As Rama prepares to fire his arrow, Vashishta ... tells the offending king to throw himself at Vishwamitra's feet.  The king does so, still repeating the mantra, and Vishwamitra is pleased and declares his act of repentance to be sufficient.

Comment: @@Keshav- Can you please let us know which purana or scripture the above story of Hanuman fighting Raama. Forget about one Hanuman, crores of Hanumans cannot stand in front of Lord Raama, in real war

Comment: @Krishna I mentioned in my answer that I don't think it has any scriptural basis.  It's probably just some folk tale.  And of course Hanuman couldn't defeat Rama in battle.  But the message of the story is that Rama's name is even more powerful than Rama's arrows.

Comment: @@Keshav - sorry, i missed that folklore point. But, then you could have put that statement at the begining of your answer and also say that there is no scriptural proof available for this fictitious story. I know some 19-20 century poet wrote Krishna Arjuna yuddham, which is a wild fantasy. This was made into a movie. Similarly, Rama Anjaneya yuddham

Comment: Sage Vishwamitra , the Guru, asking his pupil Rama, to kill anybody other than Asuras who threatened Gods, or disturbed Yagyas and such austerity rituals,is actually - trying to show sage Vishwamitra in very poor light.Sage Vishwamitra would never do anything like that.He was a distinguished sage of the Treta Yuga and not from this Kaliyuga! As mentioned above,the story can have  no scriptural basis.

Comment: "As far as I know, this story has no scriptural basis; it may just be folklore." @Keshav Srinivasan.  The evidence from comparative mythology overwhelmingly shows what we call scripture has lots of folkloric elements in it.  Also, It may be "scriptural" except that it has not been found yet.  the Gaudiyas claim to have "discovered" something they call "the brahna samhita" in the past few centuries.

Comment: @SK I disagree, and I think comparative mythology is the wrong way to approach this issue.  Hindu scripture can be proven to be true, in a way that other scriptures cannot be.  See Adhyaya 1 Pada 1 of the Purva Mimamsa Sutras for details.

Comment: "Hindu scripture can be proven to be true" @keshav srinivasan - of course - right you are - the Sun IS closer to the earth than the moon.  Centuries of western science is wrong.

Comment: First of all, there is a hierarchy of Pramanas: Pratyaksha or perception, Anumana or inference, and Sabda or scriptural testimony.  Anumana is only authoritative over that concerning which Pratyaksha is silent,  and Sabda Pramana is only authoritative over that concerning which Pratyaksha and Anumana are silent.  So I certainly don't think the Sun is closer to the Earth than the Moon.  But second of all, there need not be a contradiction here; see Richard Thompson's book "Vedic Cosmography and Astronomy" for one attempted reconciliation (though I don't agree with everything he says).

Answer (score 6):

This story has no validity in any valid scriptures.

Maybe it is there in Parasara Samhita, not sure, but this Samhita itself appears to be later day work and has lot of interpolations.

So, there no validity in this story.

> 1. First of all, Hanuman being a strict devotee of Raama, will never fight Raama nor did he ever fight Raama.
> 2. Secondly, if you look at Srimad Valmiki Ramayana, Hanuman himself says that neither bramha nor siva, nor Indra etc can wage a war and win against Raama. so, neither hanuman nor anyone can stand a chance against Raama in a war.
> 3. Thirdly, in padma purana, Hanuman took on Lord Siva and his attendents and defeated all of them after the aswamedha yaga, when Siva and his retinue came to aid of a king who captured the Sacrificial Horse set loose by Lord Raama as part of Aswemedha yagna (remind you only Satrughna and Hanuman, Sugriva, Ayodhya army and Vanara army fought against Siva and his ganas. Raama, Lakshmana and Bharata were not there). This incident is in Padma Purana.
>      Hanuman chastises Siva for fighting Satrughna and Ayodhya Army and bashes Siva and his ganas, though Siva was just trying to keep his word given to his devotee, the king who had captured the Horse. So, Hanuman, will never fight or agree to fight Rama.
>
> So, it is very unlike, such a devote Hanuman will listen to his mother's promise about some dharma etc., and fight Raama whatever may be the reason.

This is fictitious story just to convey a message that the name of Lord Vishnu/Rama is as powerful as the Lord himself.

If you look at the Padma Purana, the very same Hanuman becomes unconciouness during a fight with Lava and Kusha, Raama's sons. Both Hanuman and Sugriva are captured by Lava and Kusha.

> So, neither Hanuman nor anyone can stand a chance against Raama in a war.

So, this story has no validity in the valid Hindu scriptures.

Comment: Where did you even get the idea that it may be mentioned in the Parashara Samhita?

Comment: if user808 cannot cite where in the Padmapurana Hanuman "bashes Siva and his ganas" this post should be deleted.  I'll take at up at the highest level possible if moderators don't act on this.

Answer (score 2):

Sri Sri Ramakrishna once mentioned an incidence: When Sri Rama arranged for the Agnipariksha (Fire trial) for Sita mata, and She was entering the flame created for the purpose, Hanumanji was very disappointed and was about to wage a war with Sri Rama. But, it is also believed that this trial was arranged by Lord Rama only to facilitate the exchange of Maya Sita with real one.

It is also believed that Sita Herself was strong enough to protect Herself from Ravana, but She did not do it for a few reasons:
1. Ravana got hold of Maya Sita only. 
2. As the universal mother personified (even in Her Maya version), She will never kill any person... Nor even anybody can die in front of Her, such is Her love for all of us.

Her strength had been demonstrated in Her childhood when She used to play with the Hara Dhanu (the famous Bow of lord Shiva) that could not be moved by any of the kings (nor even by all of them together) except Shri. Rama who eventually broke it.

Please remember these are only sweet beliefs for those who have attained faith and ready to believe. I don't remember the references.

Comment: It would be more useful if quote from Sri Ramakrishna is referenced with some verifiable links or books.