# Why lord Ram used Brahmastra to kill Hanuman but failed?

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman

What is the story and why lord Ram want to kill Hanuman and finally used Brahmastra but failed? How could the Brahmastra failed?

Comment: _"How could the Brahmastra failed?"_ Because Hanuman got boon from Brahma that you(Hanuman) will be free from effect of any astra of mine(Brahma). He got that boon in childhood after incident of eating Sun.

Comment: @Rishabh, oh nice boon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not export to answer these kind of question but will try to post here, what i read and watched in Movies.

There were two ways of explanation for this question.

1-> [Because of Kashi king](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/834/why-did-hanuman-fight-with-lord-rama)

2-> [RAM Nama is powerful Than RAMA himself](http://blog.onlineprasad.com/what-was-the-reason-behind-lord-rama-attacking-hanuman/) Proved by Narada muni

No `astras` in this world will kill Hanuman, not only Brahmastra, Even Loard Shiva's Pashupathastra, Loard Vishnu Sudharshan Chagra etc